# Rogue CMTS / authentication of CMTS

Tags: security, authentication, docsis

For DOCSIS 3.0 and 3.1, what would happen if I plug in a CMTS at my end of the coax cable? Can there be more than one CMTS on the network and would it be possible for other people on the network to spoof a CMTS? How can I ensure I connect to the right end?